# Adding d.ts for vanilla function which returns a function that wraps functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

I have a complex function in my vanilla JS code (see later for simple example) that gets `export`d, and I want to add a `d.ts` to it.

So far my attempts at writing the `.d.ts` have not forwarded the types from the intermediate stage on to the final stage

The function/s looks like this (I've simplified it as much as possible whilst maintaining the same structure)

```
const factory = (x, y = 0) => {
    const z = x + y;
    return fn => {
        const p = Promise.resolve(z).then(console.warn);
        return (...args) => p.then(() => fn(...args));
    };
};
```

Example usage

```
const A = factory(1, 2);
const fn = (a1, a2) => a1 + ' world' + a2; // (a1: string, a2: string) => string
const B = A(fn); // (i: string, j: string) => Promise<string>
B('hello', '!'); // warns 3 and returns a Promise<string> "hello world!"
```

So as you can see from my comments, the arg types expected when invoking `B` is the same as `fn`, the return type of `B` is a *Promise* of the return type of `fn`

---

What I've tried so far

```js
declare function factory(x: number):
    (fn: (...U: any) => T) =>
        (...U) => Promise<T>;
declare function factory(x: number, y: number):
    (fn: (...U: any) => T) =>
        (...U) => Promise<T>;
```

However,

- When looking at `B` all type information is lost about `fn` and I am left with `any[] => Promise<any>` when I expect `(string, string) => Promise<string>`
- The description of the return type is duplicated multiple times

I've also tried writing in an interface-y way, but this has the same problem of types getting lost and I don't see how you'd reference them

```
declare function factory(x: number): wrapper;
declare function factory(x: number, y: number): wrapper;
interface wrapper {
    (fn: function): wrapped;
}
interface wrapped {
    (...args: any): Promise<any>;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the result function to have the same arguments as the function passed as the argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the final function to have the same arguments as the function you pass as a parameter, if I understood the question correctly. While you can't do this for an arbitrary number of parameters you can define overloads for functions with up to 4 parameters for example and add more if you need them later:

```
declare function factory(x: number): Promiseify;
declare function factory(x: number, y: number): Promiseify;

interface Promiseify {
    <T>(fn: () => T): () => Promise<T>;
    <T, U1>(fn: (arg1: U1) => T): (arg1: U1) => Promise<T>;
    <T, U1, U2>(fn: (arg1: U1, arg2: U2) => T): (arg1: U1, arg2: U2) => Promise<T>;
    <T, U1, U2, U3>(fn: (arg1: U1, arg2: U2, arg3: U3) => T): (arg1: U1, arg2: U2, arg3: U3) => Promise<T>;
    <T, U1, U2, U3, U4>(fn: (arg1: U1, arg2: U2, arg3: U3, arg4: U4) => T): (arg1: U1, arg2: U2, arg3: U3, arg4: U4) => Promise<T>;
}
const A = factory(1, 2);
const fn = (a1: string, a2: number) => a1 + ' world' + a2; // (a1: string, a2: number) => string
const B = A(fn); // (arg1: string, arg2: number) => Promise<string>
B('hello', 1); // ok 
B('hello', '1'); // error
```

Comment: Saddening that you can't do arbitrary, but this looks to work well for reasonable known-length, thanks!